# Odoo: Set default team of a module from settings page

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

Having created a view on the res.config page, I implemented a many2one field which lists the set of existing teams on the Helpdesk Module. What I would like to do is set the default helpdesk team upon the creation of a ticket automatically (By default this is "Customer Care"). So basically, the team the user chooses in my custom field on the res.config view would be the default helpdesk team. What would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be easily achieved using the `context` in the action:

```xml
<field name="context">{'default_team_id': active_id}</field>
```

or you could do it programmatically (not advisable) using `lambda` default function as following:

```py
team_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='helpdesk.team', default=_default_team_id)

def _default_team_id(self):
    team_id = self.env.ref('my_module.best_team_ever').read()[0]
    return team_id
```

```py
# update using configuration would be:
def _default_team_id(self):
    get_param = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param
    default_team = get_param('helpdesk.my_custom_default_team')
    return default_team
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that I'm creating an action. What if I wanted to put this custom field under "general settings" in res.config? Also why wouldn't you advise a server side solution?

Comment: of course you could get the team id from res.config. I don't advise using hard-coded method. because xml can be changed during production without blocking the user.

Comment: So after inheriting the general setting view, would that be
`<field name="custom_field"  context= "{'helpdesk.default_team_id': active_id}"/>`